# using define() and require() in requireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, js-amd

I understand that `define()` is used to crete a module

`require()` is used to retrieve the data.

I have `script1.js` which contains

```
define(['dependency1'], function(dep1){
     var operation = {
         addition: function(a, b){
            return a + b;
         }
     };        
     return operation;
});
```

I use the code in `script2.js`

```
require(['script1'], function(x){
    console.log(x.addition(11, 8));
})
```

Is there a better way to use require and define to achieve the same result?

Comment: That looks right to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No "better" way I can think of--that looks right to me. (I'm more used to CommonJS/Browserify, but this still should work.)